# Material UI - Avoid line break between Typography components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to apply two different Typography tags to my text, but I don't want a line break in between.

This is what I have:

```
<Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
  Project:
</Typography>
<Typography variant="subheading" color="inherit" noWrap>
  Example
</Typography>
```

This is what it looks like (with the line break):

[image]

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jzmz7klzmy

How do I remove the line break?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap those in a display:flex and it will show it in a row.

```
<div style={{display:"flex"}}>
  <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
     Project:
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="subheading" color="inherit" noWrap>
       Example
  </Typography>
</div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k1oowzr05v) of edited code.

**Edit:** You can use `style={{marginLeft:10}}` on `Example` to give spacing between the two.
And if you want to align them vertically, give `flexDirection:'column'` to the `style` of `Project`.

Comment: Thank you, can you please show how to create spacing between the two? Also, how to align them vertically at the bottom? Here is a gist: https://codesandbox.io/s/llqry78p29

Comment: Added an edit with your new requirement. Please accept the answer for the stack overflow community.

Comment: I've updated the gist with your feeback: https://codesandbox.io/s/llqry78p29 However, the flexDirection:'column' is NOT aligning them vertically. Please help! I will award answer if this is possible

Comment: By `vertical` I thought one below the other. You wanted both to be aligned in a center line, right? I haev updated the codesandbox, pls check https://codesandbox.io/s/6lyp9wqyw3

Answer (score 18):

Use the display prop on version 4.x

```
<Typography variant="h1" color="inherit" display="inline">
  Project:
</Typography>
<Typography variant="subtitle1" color="inherit" display="inline">
  Example
</Typography>
```

Use the inline prop on version < 4.x

```
<Typography variant="title" color="inherit" inline>
  Project:
</Typography>
<Typography variant="subheading" color="inherit" inline>
  Example
</Typography>
```

https://material-ui.com/api/typography/

Comment: Updated with latest version's API

Comment: How did you create different variants then the default ones?

Comment: it was based on the OP example, updated with latest API

Comment: Cool, Material UI 5 now offers variants by default on the theme definition.

Comment: Awesome.  I'll keep an eye out for the release!