# Why is My Space Becoming a New Line using the Material UI Grid System?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, jss

I'm having the most difficult time working with the [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) Grid system. I'm trying to achieve something relatively simple--keeping Icon + Text to the left of a container, and pushing a button to the right. However, I'm finding that any of my text that has two words with a space becomes two lines, and I have no idea why this is happening or what to do about it.

#### Setting Up the React Fragment

```
<>
  <Grid className={classes.rowLayout} display="inline">
    <SomeIcon />
    <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>&nbsp;Title Text</Typography>
    <Grid container justify="flex-end">
      <Button />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</>
```

#### The rowLayout JSS Class

```
...
rowLayout: {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'baseline',
}
...
```

### What it Looks Like Now

[image: Text with a Space Incorrectly Wraps]

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch,

Davis

Comment: Did you provided enough "space" for the text (width = ?) and why not justify-content next to display:flex?

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? Or full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you want behaving like an item in material-ui should be wrapped in a Grid item. And the items in a Grid container, as shown in the examples [here](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/).
The structure should be something like this (regarding the container/items). If you have enough space like in the image you posted, the text should not break line before the button.

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <EditIcon />
        <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
          Title Text
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Button>button </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If you do not want the text line to break in any way, you can check how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048504/material-ui-avoid-line-break-between-typography-components).